# how to get userinput formatted text from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I used textarea to upload the user discription into the database of phpmyadmin. User can use any characters and spaces, new line, and other special characters. When I retrive the infomation from the database its showing all in one para with no formatted text. I want the text to appear the same as the user inserted like how its appearing in the forums. Below are the codes I used....

Input html

```
<textarea class="noticearea" name="notice_area" id="notice_area" required="required"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["notice_area"]); ?></textarea>
```

php read

```
$notice_area = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["notice_area"]);
```

SQL insert

```
$noticeinsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notice (notice_area) VALUES ('$notice_area')");
```

retrive infomration

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($notice_area); ?>
```

Everything is fine no error or warning. I can retrive easily but not in a format. Please suggest me if i have to add any code.

Comment: use `nl2br($notice_area)`

Comment: for sending to databse or retriving ?? if retriveing no need of htmlspeacialchar ??

Comment: Try using `htmlspecialchars()` on the string to put into the DB, and then, when pulling it back out, use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` or `nl2br()`

Comment: now i use nl2br(htmlspecialchars($selectnotice)) its working perfect.. can i keep it like this ??

Comment: Please note: Phpmyadmin is an application that makes it easier to manage databases. There is however no such thing as a 'phpmyadmin database'. The database is in your case a mysql database.

Comment: _“Try using htmlspecialchars() on the string to put into the DB,”_ – nope, don’t. Apply necessary escaping for a given _context_ only when you are transferring the data _into that context_. The context here is HTML, and the data is transferred into that context when it is _output_, not _input_ – so htmlspecialchars should be applied after the data is read from DB, and before it’s output into the page.

Answer (score -1):

You might need the following code for displaying.

```
// $notice_area assumes you have database query and the reuslt is correctly fetched.

echo str_replace("\\r\\n","<br/>", (htmlspecialchars(($notice_area))));
```

### Why?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

**mysql_real_escape_string()** will add slashes prior to **\n , \r**, so on.

after inserting into db then are then **\n \r** in plain text because you added them by **\\n and \\r**.

so after getting the plain text of **\n and \r**, you need to replace them with 
, then it is it :D

Comment: _“mysql_real_escape_string() will add slashes prior to \n , \r, so on.”_ – it will only add those slashes so that the database _interface_ understands it correctly. That _does not_ mean that those slashes actually end up _in_ the data that is stored into the database.

Comment: it will only add those slashes so that the database interface understands it correctly. "after inserting into db are then \n \r in plain text " is telling that. what i mean is \\n and \\r is passing to the database query interface and the result text is the slash and n/r. :)